# Stone -Weierstrass theorem

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis

> let $A$ be a set of continuous  functions over the closed interval $[0,1]$, which applies to the following conditions:
>
> $ 1: \forall f \in A , \forall x \in [0,1] , f(x) \geq 0 $
>
> $2: \forall f, g \in A , f + g \in A $
>
> $3:  \forall x \in [0,1], \textbf{there is}   f \in A  \quad \textbf{so that} f(x) > 0 $

**By Stone -Weierstrass theorem** , How can I Prove "that there is $  h \in A$  so that $ \forall  x \in [0,1], h(x) > 0$" ?.

> Should I use the below theorem?

**THEOREM:**

Let A $\subset C(K)$ such that

1) A is a subalgebra with unity 1

2) For each $\ x_1, x_2 \in K $ with $\ x_1 \neq  x_2 $, exist $f \in A$ such that f($\ x_1$) $ \neq $ f($\ x_2$).

Then $ \overline A = C(K)$, where C(K) is the space of continuous functions over a compact space

Comment: It does not seem like you can use the theorem. Consider $A := \{f: [0,1] \to \mathbb R|\, \forall x: f(x) = c \geq 0\}$. This $A$ does not satisfy condition 2) of your theorem, but it does satisfy 1,2 and 3 above.

Comment: You recieved an answer to your question. Is it what you needed? If so, you should upvote and accept it.

Answer (score 2):

I would use compactness: find for every $x$ a function $f_x$ as in 3), also take $\delta_x>0$ such that $f_x$ is positive inside the $\delta_x$-nbd of $x$. Now apply compactness to reduce to finitely many function and add them.

Addendum: there are finitely many $x_1$, ..., $x_n$ such that $[0,1]$ is covered by the corresponding $\delta_{x_i}$-nbds. Now take $f=f_{x_1}+\cdots+f_{x_n}$.

Comment: please, give me more guidance about "apply compactness to reduce to finitely many function and add them. "? Thanks.

Comment: I have expanded the answer a bit.